# how to start Zxing on a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

i have an activity that holds Two Fragments, 
i want to run ZXING scanner on one of the fragments,

currently i do this on another activity like this >

```
new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan(); // opens up Scan intent > ZXING
```

how do i do that line but to open up the scan on a fragment ?

Also i get the ZXING results on a reciever like this >

```
//results when activity enters a callback sent out to another activity
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
```

how will i get them on my Fragment that i'm going to run Zxing on ?

THNX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how do i do that line but to open up the scan on a fragment ?

Use getActivity() to pass Context in `IntentIntegrator` as:

```
new IntentIntegrator(getActivity()).initiateScan();
```

> how will i get them on my Fragment that i'm going to run Zxing on ?

override `onActivityResult` in both Fragment container Activity with `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` line  and in    Fragment just override `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: how to use a call back in fragment itself

Answer (score 15):

If you really need to open it in a support fragment you can use:

```
IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(MyFragment.this).initiateScan();
```

In your Fragment:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
  String barcode = result.getContents();
}
```

Try it!

Comment: Bro, you save my life. Thanksssss

Comment: It's giving me `error: cannot find symbol
            IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan();`

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 : Include Dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Step 2: in the OnCreateView, let a button be clicked to initiate the scan of the qr code

```
scan_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Please focus the camera on the QR Code");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
         }
    });
```

Step 3: in the parent activity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(scanResult != null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "  >>>>"+scanResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(">>>>"," "+scanResult.getContents().toString());
    }
}
```

Now the qr code's decoded content appears in the log files and as a toast!

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers are correct and i wanted to add how I did it.

Step 1:

```
implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
```

Step 2:
In My activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Step 3:
In my fragment

```
requestCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Request camera
            IntentIntegrator integrator = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(ScanFrag.this);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan QR code");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
```

And I override

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Log.d("ScanFrag", "Cancelled scan");
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.d("ScanFrag", "Scanned | " + result.getContents());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help someone looking how to use xzing from a fragment

Answer (score 0):

Following code works good. -

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity()) {
    @Override
    protected void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
        EditorFragment.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 312); // REQUEST_CODE override
    }
};
```

Then you can override the onActivityResult, and everything works fine.

More info - [here you go.](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/291)

And then you can call your fragment's `onActivityResult` as

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragmentId);
    if(fragment instanceof ConsDetailUpdateFragment)
        ((ConsDetailUpdateFragment) fragment).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: Where do you use this code in the fragment!? and where do you use the integrator variable?

Comment: Use it inside the "BarcodeReader" class, preferably inside the setOnClickListener(). Use the integrator variable as itegrator.initiateScan() just after the above code.