# Unable to show barcode scanned text into my autocomplete text view

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, zxing, barcode-scanner, autocompletetextview

I have implemented a barcode scanner by using [Tutorial how to create Barcode Reader app in Android Studio](https://android-coffee.com/tutorial-how-to-create-barcode-reader-app-in-android-studio-1-4/#:%7E:text=Learn%20from%20this%20tutorial%20how,button%20for%20pressing%20to%20scan.). The tutorial has used `zxing integration`. I am able to configure the barcode app.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"

                android:text="Smart MSN #" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/smart_msn_spinner"
                android:layout_width="157dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:inputType="number" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/start_scan"
                android:layout_width="66dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_qr_code_scanner_24" />

        </LinearLayout>


public class NewFormFragment extends Fragment {

  @BindView(R.id.start_scan)
  ImageButton startScan;
  
  @BindView(R.id.smart_msn_spinner)
  AutoCompleteTextView smartMsnSpinner;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   bindListners();
  }

   private void bindListners() {
   .
   .
   .
   .
   startScan.setOnClickListener(startScanning);
   }

   private final View.OnClickListener startScanning = v -> {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.start_scan){
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }
    };

  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  
       IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        //smartMsnSpinner.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
        smartMsnSpinner.setText(scanContent);
    }
  }
}
```

When I start my application and click on the scan button I am able to scan a barcode. But After scanning I am seeing nothing in my `AutoCompleteTextView` i.e. `smartMsnSpinner`.

While debugging I saw that right after scanning the `breakpoint` never hits the `onActivityResult`

I must be missing something that I don't know.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you use the zxing scanner inside a `Fragment` instead of `Activity`, you may need to call `IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(NewFormFragment.this).initiateScan()`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42428384/5312102

Comment: @atarasenko It's giving me `error: cannot find symbol
            IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan();`

Comment: Include zxing library as gradle dependency: `implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.1.0'`, and then call `IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan();`. See the guide [here](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded).

Comment: @atarasenko still I am not able to use `.forFragment` or `.forSupportFragment`